Call ItemDecorator's getItemOffsets after ItemAnimator
I have an ItemDecoration that sets the margins for a view based on its spanIndex. But I also have a DefaultItemAnimator that has a default move animation. This animation can move the item and changing its spanIndex, but neither onBindViewHolder nor getItemOffset will be called for this view after animation, which creates an incorrect margin on left and right.
Problem on video
Call stack is ItemDecoration.getItemOffsets -> DefaultItemAnimator.animateMove() -> DefaultItemAnimator.onAnimationFinished()
I temporarily set recyclerview's ItemAnimator to null, which fixed the bug, but is there another full fix?
override fun getItemOffsets(
    outRect: Rect,
    view: View,
    parent: RecyclerView,
    state: RecyclerView.State
) {
    val gridLayoutParams = view.layoutParams as GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams

    val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) // item position

    if (position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
        return
    }

    if (gridLayoutParams.spanIndex == 0) {
        outRect.left = edgeSpacing
        outRect.right = horizontalSpacing
    } else {
        outRect.left = horizontalSpacing
        outRect.right = edgeSpacing
    }

    outRect.top = topSpacing
    outRect.bottom = bottomSpacing
}

